# Laravel Resource Routing not showing anything when directly call method

Tags: laravel, routes

I am stuck in resource routing
when I enter url `netbilling.test/customer` it goes to customer index file but when I enter url `netbilling.test/customer/index` nothing is returned. Also guide me if I have to route different method than in resource what is the method for that.

here is my web.php,

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard/index');
});
Route::resource('/customer','CustomerController');
```

here is my customer controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Customer;
use App\Package;
use Redirect,Response;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $packages = Package::get();
        $customers = Customer::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('customer/index', compact('customers','packages'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       //
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {

    }
 }
```

Comment: you need to add the route to /customers/index in your routes file.
you only have the route to /customer. that is why only /customer works

Comment: `customer/index` would match `customer/{customer}` which is your `show` route which returns nothing .... you are missing a `destroy` method for that controller. btw

Comment: Kofi Mokome I am using resource route so that I use /customer only..

Answer (score 0):

Without custom route specification, this is how the index route maps to a Resource Controller, taken from [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller):

| Verb | URI | Action | Route Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GET | `/photos` | index | photos.index |

So if you want URI `/customer/index` to work, then you need to specify this explicitly in your Controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController;

Route::resource('customer', CustomerController::class);
Route::get('customer/index', [CustomerController::class, 'index'])->name(customer.index);
```